# How do I get the latest row by date t-sql for each file id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure I am creating, the columns are Id, UserId, xId, DocId, FileName, FileType, FileSize, DateUploaded, UploadedBy

There can be multiple copies of the DocId for historic reasons, and I need to return only the newest row for each DocId.

I appreciate any help or pointers as I am new to SQL

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.EDocument a
    INNER JOIN dbo.Document b ON
        a.Id = b.Id
    INNER JOIN dbo.FileType c ON
        c.Id = b.FileType
WHERE @UserId = UserId
ORDER BY DateUploaded
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generic way to remove duplication.

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM Table T1
WHERE DateUploaded = (SELECT MAX(DateUplaoded FROM Table T2 WHERE T1.DocId = T2.DocId)
```

Comment: It is possible for this query to return multiple rows.  This would occur when there are multiple rows in the table for the same docid where the max DateUploaded is also duplicated.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. Thanks for pointing out.